# How to delay Trigger(starting time) of repeating alarm?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-alarms, android-pendingintent

The problem is that I want to delay the repeating-alarm's first fire.
for example I want this pending intent work after 10 mins of the click not right away, how to do that?

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, ReportService.class);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Main.this, 0, intent, 0);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), 112500, pendingIntent);
}
```

the 2nd paramater in this setInexactRepeating called triggerAtMillis
From Android developer guide:
triggerAtMillis     time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type). This is inexact: the alarm will not fire before this time, but there may be a delay of almost an entire alarm interval before the first invocation of the alarm.

Iam changing it and it always start on the click and does no delay, any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the
  [developer link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) here. The second parameter is triggerAtMillis. It used as **time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go off**

So in your case, add the extra milliseconds to `c.getTimeInMillis()`, after which you want to first run your pending intent. :)

Comment: Thank you,
it worked by adding the desired delayed time summed to the getTimeInMillis() in the 2nd paramater:
              alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis() + 180000, 180000, pendingIntent); 
//start after 3 minute & repeat every 3 minute

Comment: thank you , I'm tired to find this answer :
" add the extra milliseconds to c.getTimeInMillis() "
BIG thanks

Answer (score 0):

check into handler.postDelayed function where you can specify a delay

Answer (score 0):

If using the ELAPSED_REALTIME clock, do this

```
manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+180000,
                180000,
                pendingIntent);
```

Do not use zero or System.currentTimeMillis() as an offset for the ELAPSED clock.